# Apache windows service ran under custom identity wont start

Tags: apache-2.4, windows-server-2012-r2, service

I have a new windows 2012 R2 server and I am trying to install apache 2.4 as a service with a custom local user made specifically for Apache.

I have the user rights assignment to allow logon as a service..and given the entire apache program directory modify permissions. However, it refuses to run. When I try to run the service, it just stops with an error that shows up in the system event log as "incorrect function" no further details.

I should note that I have successfully created a custom service identity for MySQL 5.7 and that runs fine.

So my question is, am I missing something? Is there something special that has to be done in 2012 R2?

****UPDATE****

It should also be noted, that if I add that custom user identity to the local administrators group, it will run. But this compromises the security.

Comment: I would recommend logging in as the user, then manually running Apache in a command window so you can see if Apache is throwing any errors.

Comment: Apache in windows, better not use linux or IIS ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, for some reason, setting the permissions on the Apache directory didn't inherit properly. Some files in bin had limited access. I when and forced replacement and inheritance of the permissions into the full directory and any sub-directories and files to achieve modify permissions across the board. I can now run the service without relying on admin privileges.